# Proper Way To Store Metrics in SQL Growth vs Total Number

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a question about database design.

I'm trying to store the subscriber count on certain subreddits on reddit.

I'm trying to think of the proper way to structure my data.

Potential Scenarios:

1. Should I store the data such that it is just the total? I then would have to use application logic to determine the growth.
2. Should I store the data such that it is just the growth number i.e. +1, -10, +120, etc.

Note: Both of these stats are important to me: Growth and Total. So I do want relatively easy access to both of them.

I thought originally I would just store both, but that seems to go against normalization and trying to not have redundancies in my database.

Here is a quick example.

Scenario 1. 
Subreddit: /r/test
Time: 12:00
Count 1200

Scenario 2.
Subreddit: /r/test
Time: 12:00
Growth: +100

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have daily totals?  Can't all the reports be derived from those?

Comment: Yes, I guess what I was asking is should I just be calculating growth on the fly? Even if the data gets to an extremely large amount

Comment: Is "growth" defined as "the total through today" - "the total through yesterday"?  But that it "today's total"?